# Is it possible/necessary to have call to OnDraw in separate thread [MFC]

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

This is a MFC Doc/View application:
Is it possible/necessary to have call to OnDraw in separate thread of execution, i.e. worker thread?  In the software we building we have enormous problem with view in Doc/View application. That is, every time the view is scrolled the processing of this takes such long time that the application freezes.
The bitmaps that need to be processed are rather large (over 1GB on average)
Thank you.

Comment: You'd typically want to break that huge bitmap up into tiles (e.g., each roughly a size that will fit on screen) so you work with, at most, something like 4 tiles at a time, and the rest of the bitmap remains undisturbed.

Comment: I would probably have a zoomed-out copy of that bitmap, show the rough image on scroll, calculate the details in a separate thread and update the screen when ready.

Comment: Usually you should break huge pictures into pieces, as mentioned above. As to the "possible" part of your question, yes, it is possible to create a thread for drawing tasks. But I think it's unnecessary in most Doc/View applications. If the drawing task is too heavy, you should probably change to Direct2D etc.

Comment: It makes sense to start scaling activity in worker thread and skip updates in OnDraw before scaled version is ready. Once it is, you invalidate the view and have it redrawn. With scaled version ready you draw the thing you need.

Comment: @WhatsUp would using Direct2D speed things up?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando: No. Your issue isn't with rendering, it's with processing. Direct2D slows rendering down, if anything.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, thanks man! +1

Comment: @IInspectable I'm confused by "Direct2D slows rendering down". Are you meaning that D2D rendering is slower than GDI? I was saying "if the drawing task is heavy", but even in the current situation, using D2D or Ddraw you can copy just the part of the image in the view, which certainly solves the problem.

Comment: @WhatsUp: A simple BitBlt is no faster when using Direct2D instead of GDI. Taking the non-trivial overhead into account, it will be slower than using GDI. If your *"drawing task is heavy"*, use of Direct2D needs to be carefully profiled. Since Direct2D is mostly optimized for compatibility (vs. raw speed), it is often slower than GDI, or a custom Direct3D implementation, bypassing the extra D2D layer altogether.

Comment: @IInspectable This surprises me. According to MSDN: `Direct2D is a hardware-accelerated, immediate-mode, 2-D graphics API that provides high performance and high-quality rendering for 2-D geometry, bitmaps, and text.` I thought the hardware acceleration could be helpful, e.g. bitmaps are preloaded and kept in video memory, and GPU does some work, etc. Are you sure it's often slower than GDI? Are there references for this? (I could do experiments myself but can save the time if you have good reference, thx.)

Comment: @IInspectable yes, that would be nice to have established, so if you could provide refs that would be nice. thx

Comment: @IInspectable I found something from msdn which actually contradicts what you've said: "Existing GDI code will continue to work well under Windows 7. However, when writing new graphics rendering code, Direct2D should be considered, as it takes better advantage of modern GPUs." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @WhatsUp: You are quoting the proclaimed design goal of Direct2D. The implementation didn't quite meet that. The transformation of 2D shapes into D3D rendering primitives often goes for a less than optimal solution (try rendering a disc and observe what D3D primitives it generates, using the Visual Studio Graphics Debugger). [Comparing Direct2D and GDI Hardware Acceleration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729480.aspx) should give you a good idea, why a BitBlt in GDI is generally faster than a comparable Direct2D implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As specifically asked, the answer is "no".  OnDraw must be called in the context of the main GUI thread.  What you could do, is:

- Mark the scrolled region as invalid (in "OnScroll")
- Kick off another thread to extract a screen-sized bitmap from your over-large bitmap.
- OnDraw draws lots of question marks over the invalid region.
- The background thread posts a message to the main GUI thread when done.
- The message handler marks the scrolled region as now having a backing bitmap (and calls "InvalidateRect" again to prompt another OnDraw).
- OnDraw just blits the extracted bitmap in place.

(But splitting the gigantic bitmap into pieces would be a better idea.)